# how to find max if key datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have in file dictionary with datetime as key, and need to get max values for each hour for each day.
The dictionary looks like:

```
2022-11-03 00,1.76074
2022-11-03 00,1.9003
2022-11-03 01,2.0195
2022-10-03 01,2.4589
2022-10-03 01,2.5791
2022-10-03 05,2.719743
2022-10-03 05,3.8798828
```

where

```
2022 - year
10 - month
03 - day
00...05 - hour
```

The expected result should be:

```
2022-11-03 00,1.9003
2022-10-03 01,2.5791
2022-10-03 05,3.8798828
```

I tried to cycle this (for) and announce that key `datetime` object, but cant get solution for this.

code:

```
import datetime
sum_values_by_hour = {}

content = open('M2.csv', 'r') 
result = open('M2_new.csv', 'w')
for line in content:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    line_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"')
    period = line_1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
    if period not in sum_values_by_hour:
        sum_values_by_hour[period] = float(line[2])
    else:
        sum_values_by_hour[period]  += float(line[2])
    result.write(period + ',' + str(sum_values_by_hour[period]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Do you want to **edit the file** to remove the non-max items?  Or do you just want to **find** each day's max hour and then do something else with it, and leave the file as-is?

Comment: i get one file and write to enougher. yes, i want remothe non max items and write one max equal for one hour. i need only example for searching max, maybe in cycle. thanks

Comment: `1.9003` means 1 minute and 9 seconds? or it is a value recorded at that time?

Comment: @cards no, 1.9003 is value.
there: year-month-day hour,value

Comment: Shouldn't be also `2022-11-03 01,2.0195` an expected value?

Comment: @cards ,no, bethore i search sum, and use this as key and create new dict what i write to final file

Comment: @Hronus  I solved the what you posted, _" get max values for each hour for each day"_ but what you said in the last comment I haven't understood it. Could you give a better explanation? Is it so because is it the newest?

Comment: @cards, Sorry for not saying it right away. Before this, I wrote code that looked up hourly values ​​for each day. I took the file with the data above and created an empty dictionary to which I added values ​​with the datetime key. Now the values ​​in the file for each hour start at 0 and end with the maximum value. Now I want to bring the hourly record to one type with the maximum value, because this is the sum.

Comment: I still not understand the criteria, it would be more helpful if you show some code. For example you said you did a `dict` with `datetime` as key... but the dates you show are repeated so only the newest will be available!

Comment: @cards, update code above

Comment: Mmm... your code will not work: [1] array indices start from `0` and not from `1` -> correct `line`; [2] you are applying the wrong format with `strptime` (also notice nested quotes `'"%Y..."'`). PS don't forget to close the descriptors `content` and `result`at the very end with `close()`

Comment: @cards, ok, thanks a lot! Ps ‘“%Y is format in file, and I specifically used start from 1 line (or i don’t understand what you mean). Can i use your code with my and it will work?

Comment: `line_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"')` is wrong, it should be `line_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H')` as you did in the next line

Comment: [here](https://www.online-python.com/uZOpDY8vln) your version with corrections (the link expire in 24h). Now, it is missing the connection of your code with the expected value

Answer (score 0):

To sort your data wrt to time you need to cast them into a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) object and use the `key` parameter to specify the ordering via a  callback function.

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

# file content
text = """
2022-10-03 05,2.719743
2022-11-03 00,1.76074
2022-11-03 00,1.9003
2022-11-03 01,2.0195
2022-10-03 01,2.4589
2022-10-03 01,2.5791
2022-10-03 05,3.8798828
""".strip('\n')

# time format of the data in the file 
time_format = f = '%Y-%m-%d %H'

# process file content
dts = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    time_str, value = line.split(',')
    dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, f)
    dts.append((dt, float(value)))

# newest "first"
dts_sorted = sorted(dts, reverse=True, key=lambda p: (-p[0].hour, p[0]))

# get maximum of each group
dts_repr = []
for _, grp in groupby(dts_sorted, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    dts_repr.append(max(grp, key=lambda x: x[1]))

# auxiliary formatting function
output_format = '{},{}'.format

# display final result
for date, value in dts_repr:
    out = output_format(date.strftime(time_format), value)
    print(out)
```

Output

```
2022-11-03 00,1.9003
2022-11-03 01,2.0195
2022-10-03 01,2.5791
2022-10-03 05,3.8798828
```

---

Remark 1: to read from file replace the multi-lines string with the following code

```
path = 'my_data.txt'
with open(path, 'r') as fd:
    text = fd.read()
```

Remark 2: to save the results to a file (it will add an empty line at the end) modify the last block of code for example as follow

```
# save final result
fd = open('results.txt', 'w')
for date, value in dts_repr:
    out = output_format(date.strftime(time_format), value)
    print(out, file=fd)
fd.close()
```

Comment: code not work, 
at least I see the error that I encountered. Incorrect accumulation occurs after 24 hours. that is, when the 23 hour of the first day ends, the first hour of the second day is recorded in the first hour of the first day.
and incorrect grouping by days makes it difficult to read the information

Comment: my code works, it does what is required in OP. You should better explain what you want to achieve and write it in the question